# Doesn't the SeBackupPrivilege give me right to use the backup tool in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup, user-accounts, privileges

I have a regular user account on Windows 7 home premium that I wanted to give the user rights to perform backups, using the backup and restore tool.

I tried 
`ntrights +r SeBackupPrivilege –u "my_account_name"` (after installing ntrights) from the administrator account, and the command was successful. But it didn't seem to have done any good because I couldn't initiate a backup from the regular account after a reboot. I suppose I assumed wrong about user rights.

What does that command do? And how would I go about doing what I wanted?

Update: I also tried creating a new user group, adding the account and granting the group `SeBackupPrivilege` (and restore privilege) using `ntrights`. The account still can't use backup and restore.

Comment: Based on my research it appears that you have to be in the Administrator group in order to get an Administrator Privileges.  One way around this would be to create your own "Group" if you could that is and provide only the permissions you want ( i.e. this Privileges in question ).

Comment: I see. The reason I did it this way is that the home premium version of windows doesn't let me manage user groups using the MMC snap-in (that was my first strategy). I eventually did manage to create a group and add the account to it, but didn't know how to assign permissions to a group using the console. `ntrights` didn't mention that it was capable of doing that. I only find tutorials that tells me to use MMC.